# Using iReport with eclipse to generate reports approperly

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I want to use iReport with my J2EE project (JSP/Servlet) in order to generate automatically any report that I want.

I don't Know how to integrate ireport with my project and with eclipse and how to genarate reports.

Thanks for Help.

Comment: this question is way to broad and vague.  I would recommend the ireport docs (they are horrible, but at least a starting point).  Docs and training cost money but it may be worth it if you don't want to spend the research time.  sorry.

Answer (score 1):

We can integrate ireports with j2ee project using 
jasperreports-3.5.0.jar, 
commons-digester-1.7.jar,
commons-beanutils-1.8.0.jar,
commons-collections-3.2.1.jar etc...

There might be some other jar files also.

I can give you very brief code base to generate a PDF report.

Suppose your jasper file name is : "PopulationReport.jasper" and located in "E:\" directory

then the code base looks like:

Assume that **jrxmlParams** is the Map object which has the Parameters that to be passed to the jrxml and **connection** is the Database Connection object.

```
    String strFileName = "E:\PopulationReport.jasper";

    JasperReport objJReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(strFileName);

    JasperPrint objJPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(objJReport, jrxmlParams, connection);

    ByteArrayOutputStream objBAOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(objJPrint, objBAOutputStream);
```

And we can write this **objBAOutputStream** object to the User Interface(JSP or Html) in the form of byte array.