# Subreports in Jasper Reports

Tags: java, jasper-reports, report

I have two tables to be printed in same page. Data for those tables will be supplied from a map from a custom data source. I need to implement it. I googled for implementing this task.

At that time I came across sub-reports concept, but I didn't get much info for how to implement sub-reports.

I have an idea of how to create sub-reports. But I don't know how to fill sub reports with customdatasource. That's my question. Please help me in achieving this.

Note: I tried to implement subreports, but I am getting an error. Here is the code I used for compiling subreports:

```java
JasperPrint print = new JasperPrint();
JRPdfExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();
JasperDesign design, design1;
JasperReport report, report1;
JasperReport jasperReport;
JasperDesign jd1;

jd1 = JRXmlLoader.load("D:\\sub_report1.jrxml");
jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jd1);
Map parameters = new HashMap();
parameters.put("ReportTitle", "Table Report");
parameters.put("DataFile", "TableSource.java");
parameters.put("Subreport_1", jasperReport);

design = JRXmlLoader.load("D:\\sub_report2.jrxml");
report = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(design);
parameters.put("Subreport_2", report);

design1 = JRXmlLoader.load("D:\\master_report.jrxml");
report1 = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(design1);
JasperFillManager.fillReportToFile(report1, "D:\\master_report.jrprint", parameters, new TableDataSource());

exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, print);
exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE_NAME, "D:K\\Report.pdf");
exporter.exportReport();

JasperViewer.viewReport(print);
```

Here I have compiled `subreport1` & `subreport2` individually and added them as a parameter in map. Then I'm getting an error while filling it through masterreports. Please help me to compile the report.

Stack trace of the compiler error:

> Exception in thread "main" net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: Unkown print order 0.
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.initSubreportFiller(Unknown Source)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.evaluateSubreport(Unknown Source)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.evaluate(Unknown Source)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementContainer.evaluate(Unknown Source)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.evaluate(Unknown Source)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillColumnBand(Unknown Source)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillDetail(Unknown Source)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReportStart(Unknown Source)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(Unknown Source)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(Unknown Source)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(Unknown Source)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fillReport(Unknown Source)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(Unknown Source)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReportToFile(Unknown Source)
>       at ReportTableCompiler.main(ReportTableCompiler.java:53)

Comment: All the tutorials of Jasper Reports are paid. So you might not get good resources for free. You might need to check in google for some help. Here the question should be specific.

Comment: that's not true. JaspertReports, being open source, has quite a number of free tutorials.

Comment: @Purushotham: I have modified my question , can u understand now

Comment: I got the problem now. You want to generate the Reports using the Java code..

Comment: @Bozho: Ofcourse. I do have those tutorials. But the information given on that tutorials is very limited. I have the paid version of tutorials also. I can see a major difference between those two books.

Comment: @ Purusotham: yes.. i need to fill subreports through java code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted the answer for the similar question. You can check the answer here.

[Using iReport with eclipse to generate reports approperly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812614/using-ireport-with-eclipse-to-generate-reports-approperly/2988567#2988567)

Comment: u have specified code for filling a single report. but my question is that how to handle multiple reports. i.e. subreports ?

Comment: Subreport is not different from the actual report. You have to compile the sub report before it generates the report. So you can use the same code base to populate other reports(subreports).

Comment: BTW that code does not tell you how to use custom datasource. I gave that code for the ones who have some queries to populate the reports.

Comment: @purusotham: I have included the stack trace

Comment: @ purusotham : i have solved that error. that prob is becoz of higher  version of iReports. now i m getting some other error. can u understand t ?. i have included that stack trace

Comment: @Karthikeyan: I have some questions here. 
1. What does TableDataSource class contains ?
2. Do you have these two sub reports placed in the master report ?
3. What do you want to see as a final result ? A PDF or JRPrint ?
I have next set of questions also. I will ask them based on your answers for these.

Comment: @Karthikeyan: Please check which output you want. You code base contains for both PDF as well as JRPrint. Please make it either PDF or JRPrint.

Comment: @purusotham: My intention is to fill jasper with TableDatasource class and then export the output jrprint into pdf.

Comment: @purusotham: TableDatasource is a datasource class with fields for reports & its a custome datasource implemented by me.

Comment: @purusotham: i have kept those subreports inside master report. (if i double click on subreports icon in master report its opening corresponding subreport)

Comment: I have a suggestion if it is Ok with you. I am not able to recall why that runtime exception occurred offhand. Just go step by step.
First try to get the PDF of your first sub report. If there are any issues try to fix them. Try to generate the first sub report successfully. Later think of combining all the reports.

Comment: @Purusotham: I have tried it individually..Its working gr8.. with no issues.... now i don know how to compile it with master programmatic ally. !!

Comment: Can u tell me steps to compile master report ? (i.e. whole reports with 2 sub reports)

Comment: Have a look at this 

http://www.itjunky.info/programming/reports-gaphics/creating-subreport-with-jasperreport/

Comment: i m not able to open the link.. that link is not loading.(loading..........) can u pls post d content of t as answer here ?

Comment: Look into the answers section. I posted the link there.

Answer (score 1):

If you have only one detail band and your subreportExpression is something like "SUBREPORT_1.jasper" you can use this to compile several subreports

```
   JRDesignBand jrBand = (JRDesignBand) jasperDesign.getDetailSection().getBands()[0];
   JRElement[] jrElements = jrBand.getElements();
   for (JRElement jrElement : jrElements) {
       if (jrElement instanceof JRDesignSubreport) {
       JRDesignSubreport subReportDesign = (JRDesignSubreport) jrElement;
       JRExpression jrExpression = subReportDesign.getExpression();
       String file = jrExpression.getText();
       file = file.substring(1, file.length()-8)+".jrxml";
       JasperCompileManager.compileReport(file);
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sub reports are just like any other normal reports. They have own JRXML file and use own data sources. You can invoke the subreport alone or inside a master report, using the sub report tool. The data source in this case is specified in the master JRXML, the sub report properties dialog, Subreport tab, and it is different than the master's report data source.

I don't completely understand what are you trying to do, but you can also supply parameters to the sub report, so it filters its data based on the current row from the master table.

Comment: @m_pGladiato: i have modified my question pls help me solving this issue